# Is there any simplification to:$\mod(P_{k-1}\# \cdot J , \; P_k )\quad$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Is there any way to simplify or to find pattern in:

$$\mod(P_{k-1}\# \cdot J , \; P_k ) \quad with\quad J=0:P_k-1 $$
Sorry for not being clear at notaion, i will try to do it by example:

$P_k=kthprime(k)\quad$  (Example: $P_1=2\,,\quad P_2=3\,,\quad P_3=5\,, \quad etc...)$

$P_{k}\#=\prod_{i=1}^{k}P_i\quad$  (Example: $P_1\#=2\,,\quad P_2\#=6\,,\quad P_3\#=30\,, \quad etc...)$

$J$ is integer running from $0$ to $P_k-1$

And matlab code example:

```
P=primes(7), Pk=P(end), prevprimorial=prod(P(1:end-1)), J=0:Pk-1, R=mod(prevprimorial*J,Pk)
```

Output:

```
P =
     2     3     5     7
Pk =
     7
prevprimorial =
    30
J =
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6
R =
     0     2     4     6     1     3     5
```

And my question is about the residuals R, if we can find some rule for the pattern there. (Primorial inside $mod$ is with high growth of frequency and thats makes it look very chaotic)

What do i look for?

For different k we will have different $R$, the first element of $R$ (i.e. the result of $J=0$) will always be $0$.

Given $k$, i want a simple formula as a function of $k$ that will tell me what $J$ will result in residual $1$. (In the matlab example ($k=4$) the $R=1$ is result of $J=4$)

Or, alternatively, given $k$, what is the $R$ for $J=1$ . (In the matlab example ($k=4$) the $J=1$ results in $R=2$)

Or, other question, how easy it is to prove or disprove for example for $k=123456789$ the equation $\mod(P_{123456789-1}\# \cdot 987 , \; P_{123456789} ) = 123$ ?

Comment: That would help to precise from which sets those elements belong to and the meaning of the symbols you use!!!

Comment: @ mathcounterexamples, did it.

Comment: The vector R looks very far from chaotic: it is in fact an arithmetic progression mod $P_k$.  You really need to be more specific about what you are trying to simplify.  As it is (with one small optimization in the code), it takes only a bit longer to generate $R$ as it does to generate any list of length $k$.

Comment: @Erick added a clarification at the end.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks.  Are you familiar with Euclidean algorithm?  You don’t need to generate all of $R$ just to find the entry that’s 1.  If all you are interested in is that, it seems like a distraction to ask about $R$:

Comment: @Erick, but i think that Euclidean algorithm is not a simple formula. Is there any way to write a direct function of k that will output this?

Comment: That really depends on what you mean by “direct”.  Anything involving $P_k$ is unreasonable to have an explicit formula in terms of just $k$.  On the other hand, you’re just asking about $P_{k-1}^{-1}$ mod $P_k$, which I would already call an explicit and simple formula.